# Удалить некоторые элементы страницы Simple HTML DOM parser

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

Всех приветствую.

Есть такая структура страницы:

[image]

Необходимо удалить все элементы "tr", которые идут после нулевого. (Первый по счету)

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне это осуществить с помощью Simple HTML DOM parser?

Наброски:

```
    foreach($html->find('tr') as $value) {
        $value->outertext = '';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Если `$html->find('tr')` возвращает массив, то:

```
$array = $html->find('tr');
for ($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $value = $array[$i];
    $value->outertext = '';
}
```